# Adicionar múltiplos produtos ao carrinho de compras

Tags: php

Estou tentando criar um carrinho de compras simples (a principio), onde eu tenho alguns produtos fixos no banco de dados e eu estou chamando eles, obvio, através de do FetchAll();

Certo, eu fiz um $_SESSION e até onde estou conseguindo ver, esta tudo ok, mas o meu problema é que quando eu tento adicionar vários produtos no mesmo carrinho, isso não acontece. Veja o código abaixo:

```
<?php
$conection = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=meusprodutos', 'admin', 'nuttertools');

$query   = $conection->prepare("SELECT * FROM produtos");
$query->execute();
$result = $query->fetchAll();

foreach($result as $produto){
    echo 'Nome do produtos: '.$produto['nome'].'<br/>';
    echo 'Qtde do produtos: '.$produto['qtde'].'<br/>';
    echo 'Preço do produtos: '.number_format($produto['preco'], 2, ",",".").'<br/>';
    echo '<a href="carrinho.php?add=carrinho&id='.$produto['id'].'">Adicionar ao carrinho</a><br/><br/>';


}
```

na tag  existe um link para 'carrinho.php?add=carrinho&id=iddoproduto'. Aqui está o primeiro ponto:

- Eu quero enviar o produto para o "carrinho.php" mas ao inves disso, o produto está indo para o seguinte caminho: carrinho.php?add=carrinho&id=3 (<---- é o produto 3)

Além disso há outro problema. Veja o código abaixo:

```
<?php
/* Inicializa uma sessão */
session_start();

/* Verifica se já existe uma sessão ativa */
if(!isset($_SESSION['itens'])){
    $_SESSION['itens'] = array();
}

/* Inicializa uma sessão */
if(isset($_GET['add']) && $_GET['add'] == 'carrinho'){
    $idProduto = $_GET['id'];
    if(!isset($_SESSION['itens'][$idProduto])){
        $_SESSION['itens'][$idProduto] = 1;
    }else{
        $_SESSION['itens'][$idProduto] += 1;
    }
}

/* Mostrar carrinho de compras */

if(count($_SESSION['itens']) == 0){
    echo 'Carrinho Vazio<br/><a href="index.php">Adicionar Itens</a>';
}else{
    $conection = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=meusprodutos', 'admin', 'nuttertools');
    foreach($_SESSION['itens'] as $idProduto => $qtde)
    $query = $conection->prepare("SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE id=?");
    $query->bindParam(1, $idProduto);
    $query->execute();
    $produtos = $query->fetchAll();
    echo
        $produtos[0]["nome"].'<br/>';
}
```

Esse código, eu acredito que o problema esteja aqui, mais especificamente entre verificação da existencia de sessão ou ao mostrar o carrinho. 
Quando eu clico em "Adicionar ao carrinho" de cada produto lá na index.php, ele apenas leva para a página referente ao seu link:

localhost/Responsive/carrinho/carrinho.php?add=carrinho&id=1
localhost/Responsive/carrinho/carrinho.php?add=carrinho&id=2
localhost/Responsive/carrinho/carrinho.php?add=carrinho&id=3

e aí é claro, apresenta na tela, o nome do produto que é referencia do ID. Bom é isso.

O que eu quero é clicar em "adicionar carrinho" no index.php e ele ser inserido abaixo do ultimo produto (se houver) na referencia "carrinho.php". Fui claro? Espero sim, kkkk odeio ser confuso.

Espero que possam me ajudar, adicionei o código e espero não estar sendo muito extenso na questão. Bom, essa coisa de SESSION é nova pra mim e estou estudando isso agora mas ainda estou externando muitas dúvidas, aos que puderem me ajudar.

OBS: Eu vi inúmeras outras perguntas referente a esse problema mas ou elas não tinham respostas ou não era exatamente o que eu estava precisando saber. Cada caso é um caso. Se voces puderem me ajudar, eu vou poder ajudar aqueles que ainda não tem resposta ou voces mesmos podem add lá as respostas mediante ao que voces me sugeriram aqui.

Grato! Att. :D

Comment: Faça `session_start();` no topo das páginas PHP

Comment: Por que você não usou {} no seu foreach??

Comment: @MarceloUchimura já está mano ^^

Comment: @Dudut pq eu sou um besta.... '----------' não vi isso..... NAO VI ISSO '-' kkkk vlw mano kkkkk nossa, era só isso kkkkkkkkkk

Comment: Espero ter ajudado. Poderia contribuir de volta votando na minha resposta?